# Can i make two magnets orbit each other?

Tags: electromagnetism

For an orbit to exist there must be two force canceling each other in this case assume magnetic(attractive force) and centrifugal force.
Can I equate both of them so that an orbit exists?

Comment: Discussed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2-EqVdaNT4). Such an orbit quickly destabilizes [because of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation#Cotes_spirals) [its force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Magnetic_dipole–dipole_interaction).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

An orbit requires a centripetal force which accelerates an objects toward the center. Any attractive force can be used as the centripetal force required for an orbit. It doesn't matter if that force is due to gravitational attraction, electromagnetism, or is simply the tension in a string tying the two objects together.